# escaping for objects.raw()

Tags: django

I need a custom SQL query and try to use this:

```
Log.objects.raw("SELECT pub_date FROM foo_log GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(pub_date,'%Y%m%d')")
```

I get this error: *TypeError: not enough arguments for format string*

So how can I escape this %Y strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you escape a `%` with another `%`, e.g.:

```
Log.objects.raw("SELECT pub_date FROM foo_log GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(pub_date,'%%Y%%m%%d')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then raw SQL you could use [dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.dates) for the above query.

```
Log.objects.dates('pub_date', 'day')
```

would return all the distinct dates by y/m/d